# Show specific, private documents on a user homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am new to SharePoint and excited about what it could help to achieve and trying to figure out the possibilities. I am using Office 365 EDU package.

My question

Person 1 owns 6 documents, A.docx, B.docx and so on in a folder in their one drive. Each document is shared with one other person.  Is it possible to easily arrange so that

Person 2 homepage contains clear link to A.docx
Person 3 homepage contains clear link to B.docx
Person 4 homepage contains clear link to C.docx

Ideally, Person 1 homepage contains clear link to all documents.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you share file via OneDrive, basically it generates a URL which can be used to access the file directly.

In order to make your requirement work, first Person1 should

1. Create a "Document Library" in SharePoint and upload all documents
   into that library
2. Stop Inheriting permissions on that library - so other users won't be able to see the content
3. Edit home page and document library to the home page
4. Go back to the library and Share Individual file to other users

Now once other users login to SharePoint, they will be able to see direct links to the shared documents.

Comment: If it's one drive for business it gets indexed by search, doesn't it? Can try to use Content Search to list the documents the person has permissions to on the main page.

Comment: @Choggo yes that is a valid point. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks to the first answer, it is now working brilliantly.  This will really help the site's users to work more collaboratively and without delays. The idea about search sounds interesting, but I don't know how to add a search yet.  Is it hard to do?

Comment: @JustinHeath since its SharePoint online by default the search crawl will be set up. The only thing you need to do is edit page and add "Content Search" webpart. Then change the property settings so it displays only the relevant documents. Your decision on using SharePoint doc lib is wonderful. SharePoint is the platform if you are planning for collaboration. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/should-i-save-my-documents-to-onedrive-for-business-or-a-team-site-HA104105232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Amal's answer, if the files are stored at the One Driver for Business(from the my site feature of SharePoint) you can use the [Content Search Web Part](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html) to list the documents that are stored in SharePoint and since before showing the results, SharePoint applies the user's permissions to the results the users will only see the files shared with them.

You can tweak the results, to display files only from specific areas or of specific content types as well.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It's a little bit beyond my skill at present. I'll try to learn it, as I'm sure it'll help as we grow into using SharePoint in the future.